# moving average for plotly

Tags: python, plotly

so I'm trying to code candlesticks chart via Plotly library and I'm trying to add moving average lines in my code.
I search for many codes to implement MA to my code, but I couldn't figure out how to add MA lines at the same candlesticks chart.

Waiting for someone to help me with this.

```
import shrimpy
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import plotly.express as px 
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# sign up for the Shrimpy Developer APIs for your free API keys
public_key = ''
secret_key = ''
# collect the historical candlestick data
client = shrimpy.ShrimpyApiClient(public_key, secret_key)
candles = client.get_candles(
    'binance', # exchange
    'BNB',     # base_trading_symbol
    'BTC',     # quote_trading_symbol
    '1d'       # interval
)
dates = []
open_data = []
high_data = []
low_data = []
close_data = []
# format the data to match the plotting library
for candle in candles:
    dates.append(candle['time'])
    open_data.append(candle['open'])
    high_data.append(candle['high'])
    low_data.append(candle['low'])
    close_data.append(candle['close'])

# plot the candlesticks
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=dates,
                       open=open_data, high=high_data,
                       low=low_data, close=close_data)])

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 30):

I simplify your code with `pandas` and using `rolling` function to calculate the moving averages.

```
import shrimpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# sign up for the Shrimpy Developer APIs for your free API keys
public_key = ''
secret_key = ''
# collect the historical candlestick data
client = shrimpy.ShrimpyApiClient(public_key, secret_key)
candles = client.get_candles(
    'binance', # exchange
    'BNB',     # base_trading_symbol
    'BTC',     # quote_trading_symbol
    '1d'       # interval
)

df = pd.DataFrame(candles)

df['MA5'] = df.close.rolling(5).mean()
df['MA20'] = df.close.rolling(20).mean()


# plot the candlesticks
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.time,
                                     open=df.open, 
                                     high=df.high,
                                     low=df.low,
                                     close=df.close), 
                      go.Scatter(x=df.time, y=df.MA5, line=dict(color='orange', width=1)),
                      go.Scatter(x=df.time, y=df.MA20, line=dict(color='green', width=1))])
```

Plot:
[image]

Comment: Man, you saved my life. I wanna marry you right now Lool.
Thank you very much for your help, God bless you.

Comment: . Now I have the dots visible on the moving average lines. If I add mode='lines' to the parameters of go.Scatter, the dots are not visible.

Comment: @SerhiiKushchenko Probably you solved it already but for others who google it : b_ is the smoothed column, b is the original column


``fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_temp["date"], y= df_temp[b_], mode='lines', name=b, line=dict(
            color='LightSkyBlue')))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_temp["date"], y=df_temp[b], mode='markers', name = b, showlegend=False,marker=dict(
            color='LightSkyBlue',
            size=2)))``